# Does anyone know how to make this energy spreading effect

Tags: modeling, fluid-simulation

I just need help in finding how to make effect of spreading energy on sword
[image]

Comment: Looks like smoke with emission material and bloom effect.

Comment: Thanks,but how to make it spreading exactly on sword